# Flutter Intercept all requests from WebView

Tags: flutter, webview, android-webview, webviewclient, flutterwebviewplugin

is there any equivalent of this in flutter for intercept all request from webview

```
webview.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
override fun shouldInterceptRequest(view: WebView?,request: WebResourceRequest? ): WebResourceResponse? {
          return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request)}}
```

thanks

Comment: You accepted answer by @Ankit_Kumar_Nath, but shouldInterceptFetchRequest method intercepts not all requests (only fetch requests).
I tried to use shouldInterceptRequest, but it does not work on iOS. 
Did you find another (universal) solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview

useShouldInterceptFetchRequest function should help!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: shouldInterceptFetchRequest method intercepts not all requests (only fetch requests).
shouldInterceptRequest works on Android but does not work on iOS.