# How to intercept all requests from WebView in Flutter (on iOS)?

Tags: flutter, webview, interceptor, flutter-inappwebview

I need to get urls and http headers for all http requests going out from WebView.

I tried to use [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) package, but it's method `InAppWebView.shouldInterceptRequest` works only on Android.
As written in their [docs](https://inappwebview.dev/docs/webview/in-app-webview/#handle-page-navigation):
"On Android, you can also use the shouldInterceptRequest event...".
But I need it to work also on iOS.

Also I tried to inject [javascript code](https://davy.ai/intercepting-fetch-request-on-flutter-webview_flutter-package/) (with interceptors) using method [`InAppWebViewController.injectJavascriptFileFromAsset`](https://inappwebview.dev/docs/webview/javascript/injection/#injecting-javascript-code-from-an-asset-file), but the injected javascript code is executed only one time (not for each request).

Also there is [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69912103/23064699) to use `shouldInterceptFetchRequest` method, but it intercepts not all requests (only fetch requests).

Any ideas?